Left and Right Contest Question TLE Kattis
I am trying to solve the Kattis problem Left and Right:

Problem D
Left and Right

With modern technology advancement, it is now possible to deliver mail with a robot! There is a neighborhood on a long horizontal road, on which there are  houses numbered 1 to  from left to right. Every day a mail delivery robot receives a pile of letters with exactly one letter for each house. Due to mechanical restrictions, the robot cannot sort the letters. It always checks the letter on top of the pile, visits the house that should receive that letter and delivers it. The robot repeats this procedure until all the letters are delivered. As a result, each of the  houses is visited by the robot exactly once during the mail delivery of a single day.
The mail delivery robot has a tracking device that records its delivery route. One day the device was broken, and the exact route was lost. However, the technical team managed to recover the moving directions of the robot from the broken device, which are represented as a string consisting of −1 letters. The -th letter of the string is ‘L’ (or ‘R’) if the (+1)-th house visited by the robot is on the left (or right) of the -th house visited. For example, if =4 and the robot visited the houses in the order of 2,4,3,1, its moving directions would be “RLL”.
With the moving directions, it may be possible to determine the order in which the robot visited the houses. The technical team has asked you to write a program to do that. There can be multiple orders producing the same moving directions, among which you should find the lexicographically earliest order.
Input
The input has a single integer  (2 ≤  ≤ 2⋅105) on the first line. The second line has a string of length −1 consisting of letters ‘L’ and ‘R’ giving the moving directions of the robot.
Output
Output the lexicographically earliest order in which the robot may have visited the houses and delivered the letters according to the moving directions. Consider two different integer sequences of equal length =(1,2,...,) and =(1,2,...,), and let
1 ≤  ≤  be the lowest-numbered index where /sub> ≠ . Then  is lexicographically earlier than  if /sub> < ; otherwise  is lexicographically earlier than .
Sample Input 1
3
LR

Sample Output 1
2
1
3

Sample Input 2
6
RLLRL

Sample Output 2
1
4
3
2
6
5

Sample Input 3
6
RRRLL

Sample Output 3
1
2
3
6
5
4


Here is the code I have developed to solve the question:
# My method is to:
# 1. group blocks of the initial Left Right sequence
# 2. loop through the groups list to get the sequence

n = int(input())
word = input()+"a" # adding in "a" for the grouping algorithm

groups = [] # list for grouping string by blocks of "R" and "L"
seq = [] # final sequence the robot moves

pos = 1 if word[0] == "R" else 0 # position will always start with 1 if the robot is moving right first

if pos == 1:
    seq = [1]

# grouping algorithm
group = word[0]
for i in word[1:]:
    if i==group[0]:
        group+=i
    else:
        groups.append(group)
        group=i

# sequence algorithm
for c, i in enumerate(groups):
    if "R" in i:
        for j in i[:-1]:
            pos+=1 
            seq.append(pos)

        if c+1 == len(groups):
            seq.append(pos+1)
        
    else:
        pos+=len(i)+1
        seq.append(pos)
        for k in range(len(i)):
            seq.append(pos-1-k)

print(*seq, sep ="\n")

Problem
The program works and solves this contest question, however I'm getting a Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error. The time limit is 1 second. And so I'm now trying to find ways to increase the speed of my program. But whatever I try, it doesn't get any faster.
I don't fully understand fast input for Python; maybe there is a way to improve the running time of that aspect? Are there more efficient ways to solve the question?

what is the ask ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please include inside the post what the purpose is of the code. Not as an image, but as text (type & format it).

If the code works and you just want to improve it, codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question. But be sure to edit your question as suggested in previous comments.

If you're asking about fast input for python, just look up tutorials online, that's not a SO question. Also look up time complexity of appending to lists in Python as that's most likely the bottleneck in your code, but in general, competitive programming problems don't necessarily have passing Python solutions since it's not a hyper fast language.


I don't fully understand fast input for python

If you follow the instructions provided by that third party site, you should be OK. On How do I handle input and output? they suggest the following as an example for I/O:

for line in sys.stdin:
    data = int(line)
    print(data)


In your case that would translate to:
_, word = sys.stdin

As you don't really need n, just discard it and don't bother casting it to int.

I'm looking to reduce the runtime

Some points where you can scrape off some execution time:

group+=i is not very efficient (where both are string variables): this creates a new string each time it executes. As you really only need the count of consecutive letters, you don't really need to build this string.

Instead of if i==group[0] for every character i, you could use the index method to find the next index that has the "other" letter. This will often be faster, certainly when there are long stretches of the same letter.

You first populate groups and then use these entries from start to end. That means you could do the two tasks in one loop and avoid creating the groups list all together

Consider using extend. The following loop:
for k in range(len(i)):
    seq.append(pos-1-k)

can be replaced by
seq.extend(range(pos-1, pos-1-len(i), -1))


You could even avoid collecting data in seq. This is not very elegant, but for the sake of speed you could immediately print the part that you would otherwise put in seq.


Here is some code that applies the above remarks:
_, word = sys.stdin
n = len(word)

if word[0] == "R":
    print(1)

j = 0
while j < n:
    # get stretch of "R" (if any)
    i = j
    try:
        j = word.index("L", i)
    except ValueError:
        j = len(word) + 1  # 1 extra for the final position
    if i + 1 < j:
        print(*range(i + 2, j + 1), sep="\n") # only positions between two "R"
    if j >= n:
        break
    # get stretch of "L"
    i = j
    try:
        j = word.index("R", i)
    except ValueError:
        j = len(word)
    if i < j + 1:
        print(*range(j + 1, i, -1), sep="\n") # positions with "L" on either side

